# PyQt Rounded progress bar

Tags: python, pyqt

Inspired from the post and code here [Any PyQt circular progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577068/any-pyqt-circular-progress-bar)
I am trying to embed four rounded progress bar in my gui application. In my gui I do not need border of the progress bar and base rectangle. How can I remove these two in the code of paintEvent.

```
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        outerRadius = min(125,110)
        baseRect = QtCore.QRectF(1, 1, outerRadius-2, outerRadius-2)  # I don't want this rectangular shape behind circular bar

        buffer = QtGui.QImage(outerRadius, outerRadius, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        buffer.fill(255)

        p = QtGui.QPainter(buffer)
        p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # data brush
        self.rebuildDataBrushIfNeeded()

        # background
        self.drawBackground(p, buffer.rect())

        # base circle
        self.drawBase(p, baseRect)

        # data circle
        arcStep = 360.0 / (self.max - self.min) * self.value
        self.drawValue(p, baseRect, self.value, arcStep)

        # center circle
        innerRect, innerRadius = self.calculateInnerRect(baseRect, outerRadius)
        self.drawInnerBackground(p, innerRect)

        # text
        self.drawText(p, innerRect, innerRadius, self.value)

        # finally draw the bar
        p.end()

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, buffer)

    def drawBackground(self, p, baseRect):
        p.fillRect(baseRect, self.palette().background())

    def drawBase(self, p, baseRect):
        bs = self.barStyle
        if bs == self.StyleDonut:
            p.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().shadow().color(),  self.outlinePenWidth))
            p.setBrush(self.palette().base())
            p.drawArc(baseRect,1,116)
        elif bs == self.StylePie:
            p.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().base().color(), self.outlinePenWidth))
            p.setBrush(self.palette().base())
            p.drawArc(baseRect,1,116)
        elif bs == self.StyleLine:
            p.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().base().color(), self.outlinePenWidth))
            p.setBrush(Qt.Qt.NoBrush)
            p.drawArc(baseRect.adjusted(self.outlinePenWidth/2, self.outlinePenWidth/2, -self.outlinePenWidth/2, -self.outlinePenWidth/2))

    def drawValue(self, p, baseRect, value, arcLength):
        # nothing to draw
        if value == self.min:
            return

        # for Line style
        if self.barStyle == self.StyleLine:
            p.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().highlight().color(), self.dataPenWidth))
            p.setBrush(Qt.Qt.NoBrush)
            p.drawArc(baseRect.adjusted(self.outlinePenWidth/2, self.outlinePenWidth/2, -self.outlinePenWidth/2, -self.outlinePenWidth/2),
                      self.nullPosition * 16,
                      -arcLength * 16)
            return

        # for Pie and Donut styles
        dataPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        dataPath.setFillRule(Qt.Qt.WindingFill)

        # pie segment outer
        dataPath.moveTo(baseRect.center())
        dataPath.arcTo(baseRect, self.nullPosition, -arcLength)
        dataPath.lineTo(baseRect.center())

        p.setBrush(self.palette().highlight())
        p.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().shadow().color(), self.dataPenWidth))
        p.drawPath(dataPath)

    def calculateInnerRect(self, baseRect, outerRadius):
        # for Line style
        if self.barStyle == self.StyleLine:
            innerRadius = outerRadius - self.outlinePenWidth
        else:    # for Pie and Donut styles
            innerRadius = outerRadius * self.donutThicknessRatio

        delta = (outerRadius - innerRadius) / 2.
        innerRect = QtCore.QRectF(delta, delta, innerRadius, innerRadius)
        return innerRect, innerRadius

    def drawInnerBackground(self, p, innerRect):
        if self.barStyle == self.StyleDonut:
            p.setBrush(self.palette().alternateBase())

            cmod = p.compositionMode()
            p.setCompositionMode(QtGui.QPainter.CompositionMode_Source)

            p.drawEllipse(innerRect)

            p.setCompositionMode(cmod)

    def drawText(self, p, innerRect, innerRadius, value):
        if not self.format:
            return

        text = self.valueToText(value)

        # !!! to revise
        f = self.font()
        # f.setPixelSize(innerRadius * max(0.05, (0.35 - self.decimals * 0.08)))
        f.setPixelSize(innerRadius * 1.8 / len(text))
        p.setFont(f)

        textRect = innerRect
        p.setPen(self.palette().text().color())
        p.drawText(textRect, Qt.Qt.AlignCenter, text)

    def valueToText(self, value):
        textToDraw = self.format

        format_string = '{' + ':.{}f'.format(self.decimals) + '}'

        if self.updateFlags & self.UF_VALUE:
            textToDraw = textToDraw.replace("%v", format_string.format(value))

        if self.updateFlags & self.UF_PERCENT:
            percent = (value - self.min) / (self.max - self.min) * 100.0
            textToDraw = textToDraw.replace("%p", format_string.format(percent))

        if self.updateFlags & self.UF_MAX:
            m = self.max - self.min + 1
            textToDraw = textToDraw.replace("%m", format_string.format(m))

        return textToDraw

    def valueFormatChanged(self):
        self.updateFlags = 0;

        if "%v" in self.format:
            self.updateFlags |= self.UF_VALUE

        if "%p" in self.format:
            self.updateFlags |= self.UF_PERCENT

        if "%m" in self.format:
            self.updateFlags |= self.UF_MAX

        self.update()

    def rebuildDataBrushIfNeeded(self):
        if self.rebuildBrush:
            self.rebuildBrush = False

            dataBrush = QtGui.QConicalGradient()
            dataBrush.setCenter(0.5,0.5)
            dataBrush.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QGradient.StretchToDeviceMode)

            for pos, color in self.gradientData:
                dataBrush.setColorAt(1.0 - pos, color)

            # angle
            dataBrush.setAngle(self.nullPosition)

            p = self.palette()
            p.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, dataBrush)
            self.setPalette(p)


class TstWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(type(self), self).__init__()

        self.bar = QRoundProgressBar()
        self.bar.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        #self.bar.setDataPenWidth(3)
        #self.bar.setOutlinePenWidth(3)
        self.bar.setDonutThicknessRatio(0.85)
        self.bar.setDecimals(1)
        self.bar.setFormat('%p %')
        # self.bar.resetFormat()
        self.bar.setNullPosition(180)
        self.bar.setBarStyle(QRoundProgressBar.StyleDonut)
        self.bar.setDataColors([(0., QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0,159,80)), (0.5, QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255,255,0)), (1., QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255,255,0))])

        self.bar.setRange(0, 100)
        self.bar.setValue(85)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.bar)
        self.setLayout(lay)


    def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = TstWidget()
        ex.show()
        app.exec_()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you minimise this to a relevant and concise example, exhibiting the issue?

Comment: I have edited the code to let only paint event remains. Now in that paint event base rect is drawn and the bar consists of outer circle and inner circle and has got color for border. I dont need border in that.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding it to a QWidget and you need it transparent you can do it like this

```
progress = QRoundProgressBar()
progress.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff")
```

note that "#ffffff" is the color of the background so set it accordingly