# PyQt: layout cuts off part of widget edges

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm trying to make a layout for my app. I designed it in Qt Designer, and in the preview everything looks right. But when I run the code, the progress bar sides are cut off.

[image: program window looks like this]

I guess I need to play with size-policy or something? Here is the actual code (the progress bar is `RoundPrg1`):

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
    self.MainVarsLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.MainVarsLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
    self.MainVarsLayout.setMargin(10)
    self.MainVarsLayout.setSpacing(10)
    self.MainVarsLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainVarsLayout"))
    #self.speedBarplace = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(2)
    #sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.speedBarplace.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    #self.speedBarplace.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    #self.speedBarplace.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 270))
    #self.speedBarplace.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("speedBarplace"))
    self.MainVarsLayout.addWidget(self.RoundPrg)#(self.speedBarplace)
    self.MainVariablesLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.MainVariablesLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainVariablesLayout"))
    self.temperaturePlace = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(2)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.temperaturePlace.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.temperaturePlace.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.temperaturePlace.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 130))
    self.temperaturePlace.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("temperaturePlace"))
    self.MainVariablesLayout.addWidget(self.temperaturePlace)
    self.fuelPlace = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(2)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.fuelPlace.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.fuelPlace.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.fuelPlace.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 130))
    self.fuelPlace.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("fuelPlace"))
    self.MainVariablesLayout.addWidget(self.fuelPlace)
    self.MainVarsLayout.addLayout(self.MainVariablesLayout)
    #self.rpmPlace = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    #sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    #sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    #sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(2)
    #sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.rpmPlace.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    #self.rpmPlace.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    #self.rpmPlace.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 270))
    #self.rpmPlace.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("rpmPlace"))
    self.MainVarsLayout.addWidget(self.RoundPrg2)#(self.rpmPlace)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.MainVarsLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.InfoLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.InfoLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
    self.InfoLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("InfoLayout"))
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    self.InfoLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
    self.InfoLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
    self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
    self.InfoLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.InfoLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.ComputerInfoLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.ComputerInfoLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ComputerInfoLayout"))
    self.PcuTempBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.PcuTempBar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.PcuTempBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.PcuTempBar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.PcuTempBar.setProperty("value", 24)
    self.PcuTempBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("PcuTempBar"))
    self.ComputerInfoLayout.addWidget(self.PcuTempBar)
    self.CpuUsageBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.CpuUsageBar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.CpuUsageBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.CpuUsageBar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.CpuUsageBar.setProperty("value", 24)
    self.CpuUsageBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("CpuUsageBar"))
    self.ComputerInfoLayout.addWidget(self.CpuUsageBar)
    self.RamUsag[eBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.RamUsageBar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.RamUsageBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.RamUsageBar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.RamUsageBar.setProperty("value", 24)
    self.RamUsageBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("RamUsageBar"))
    self.ComputerInfoLayout.addWidget(self.RamUsageBar)
    self.InfoLayout.addLayout(self.ComputerInfoLayout)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.InfoLayout, 3, 0, 1, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

[Ui file is here](http://www.filedropper.com/workinggui)
[Here is the custom widget .py file](http://www.filedropper.com/qroundprogressbar)

Comment: It might be better if you posted the qt designer ui file, rather than the pyqt code.

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry yesterday was unable to login, so post is edited with the ui file at the end.

Comment: The ui file looks nothing like the image you posted. It has ordinary push-buttons at top-left and top-right. Also, there is no progress bar named `RoundPrg1` in the python code you posted.

Comment: @ekhumoro this progress bar is custom made so there is no way I can put in qt designer (or I dont know how) and in python code there is two lines with RoundPrg1,2
<code>
        self.MainVarsLayout.addWidget(self.RoundPrg)#(self.speedBarplace)
<code>

Comment: Where did you get the code for the custom widgets? You need to provide all the code that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry didnt think about my progress bar code. I edited post and added link to the progress bar file (coz code bit too long). And thank you for your time.

Comment: It seems you got the progress bar code from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33577068/984421), and I can see the same clipping in the screenshot shown there. I suggest you ask the original author if they are able to fix the bug.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes you are right I get from that post. I will try to ask the author. Thanks!