# Circular Progress Bar using PySide

Tags: python, image, pyside

Hello friends iam trying to implement circular progress bar using PySide. Iam already downloaded the program from [Any PyQt circular progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577068/any-pyqt-circular-progress-bar). I try to convert the PyQt4 code to PySide code.But iam getting error while compiling the program. Iam using Python 2.7 version.

```
from pysidecircularprogressbar import QRoundProgressBar
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from time import sleep


class TstWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(type(self), self).__init__()

        self.bar = QRoundProgressBar()
        self.bar.setFixedSize(300, 300)

        self.bar.setDataPenWidth(3)
        self.bar.setOutlinePenWidth(3)
        self.bar.setDecimals(1)
        self.bar.setFormat('%v | %p %')
        # self.bar.resetFormat()
        self.bar.setNullPosition(90)
        self.bar.setBarStyle(QRoundProgressBar.StyleDonut)
        self.bar.setDataColors([(0., QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255,0,0)), (0.5, QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255,255,0)), (1., QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0,255,0))])
        self.bar.setMaximun(100)
        self.bar.setMinimun(0)
        self.bar.setRange(0, 100)
        self.bar.setValue(0)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start", self)

        button.clicked.connect(self.on_start)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.bar)
        self.setLayout(lay)

        self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
        self.myLongTask.notifyProgress.connect(self.on_progress)

    def on_start(self):
        self.myLongTask.start()

    def on_progress(self, i):
        self.bar.setValue(i)


class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
   notifyProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

   def run(self):
       for i in range(101):
           self.notifyProgress.emit(i)
           sleep(0.1)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TstWidget()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> Output attached below

[image]

Comment: Which part of this is C-related?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: `QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)` --> `QtCore.Signal(int)` ?

Comment: don't spam tags

Answer (score 0):

Although the names of the PySide and PyQt4 functions are almost totally compatible, they have a few differences such as the declaration of signals, so you should use `Signal` instead of `pyqtSignal`.